# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'user' since it isn't a known property of 'app-add-edit-box' & Error occurs in the template of component ShowBoxComponent

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, compiler-errors

Here is the exact error I am receiving from the terminal when I try to load the angular server. As some additional information when I open the localhost page, it says "Cannot GET /box".

```
Error: src/app/box/show-box/show-box.component.html:23:28 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'box' since it isn't a known property of 'app-add-edit-box'.
1. If 'app-add-edit-box' is an Angular component and it has 'box' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-add-edit-box' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.


23         <app-add-edit-box [box]="box" *ngIf="ActivateAddEditBoxComp"></app-add-edit-box>
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/user/show-box/show-box.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './show-box.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ShowBoxComponent.
```

I am new to using angular, and I'm not sure how to fix this error. In my show.component.html file I have what is shown below, and it was taken from the bootstrap modal.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ModalTitle}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
          (click)="closeClick()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <app-add-edit-box [box]="box" *ngIf="ActivateAddEditBoxComp"></app-add-edit-box>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have in my show.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-box',
  templateUrl: './show-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-box.component.css']
})
export class ShowUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { }

  BoxList:any=[];

  ModalTitle:string;
  ActivateAddEditBoxComp:boolean=false;
  box:any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshBoxList();
  }

  addClick(){
    this.box={
      BoxId:0,
      Box1:"",
      Box2:"",
    }
    this.ModalTitle="Add Box";
    this.ActivateAddEditBoxComp=true;
  }

  closeClick(){
    this.ActivateAddEditBoxComp=false;
    this.refreshBoxList();
  }

  refreshBoxList(){
    this.service.getBoxList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.BoxList=data;
    })
  }

}
```

Here is my add-edit-box.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-box',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-box.component.css']
})
export class AddEditBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: The error is from app-add-edit-box component. Can you paste the ts file in your question?

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Configuring the parent component](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#configuring-the-parent-component),

```
<app-add-edit-box [box]="box" *ngIf="ActivateAddEditBoxComp"></app-add-edit-box>
```

`[box]` is the property binding for the parent component which is used to pass data to the child component.

### Error

> Error: src/app/box/show-box/show-box.component.html:23:28 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'box' since it isn't a known property of 'app-add-edit-box'.
>
> 1. If 'app-add-edit-box' is an Angular component and it has 'box' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>    ...

Based on your attached source code and error message, you are missing `Input()` decorator for `box`.

---

### SOLUTION

In your `AddEditBoxComponent`, you need to declare [Input decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) for `box` to receive the value from parent component.

**Edited: Don't forget to add `Input` in the `@angular/core` import.**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-box',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-box.component.css']
})
export class AddEditBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() box: any; // Use any or class type

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: I inserted (@Input() box: any;), but I get an error that reads error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Input'

Comment: Hi @ethan4024, I had updated my answer. You need to add `Input` in your import as well.

Comment: It compiled correctly. Thankyou for helping me see the problem!